# how to change devextreme data grid boolean filter labels

Tags: angular, devextreme, dx-data-grid

The status field (last row), we want the filter options to say Active and Inactive instead of true false. There's a coding method to do this but we're creating the table using the template. I feel like this would be super easy to do I just don't see it in the documentation.

```
      <dxi-column dataField="TruckNumber" caption="Truck #" alignment="left"></dxi-column>
      <dxi-column dataField="PlateNumber" caption="License Plate #" alignment="left"></dxi-column>
      <dxi-column dataField="Phone" dataType="string" alignment="left"></dxi-column>
      <dxi-column dataField="Status" alignment="center"></dxi-column>
```

[image]

angular 4.4.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use trueText and falseText options:

```
<dxi-column dataField="Status" trueText="Active" falseText="Inactive" alignment="center"></dxi-column>
```

Comment: Don't suppose you have a link for where you found that?

Answer (score 0):

Or like that solved at reactjs.

```
<Column dataField="Status" trueText="Yes" falseText="No"/>
```